# object read as list in for ... in statement using or operator, but it is read as bool using and operator

Tags: python

This problem is loosely related to Question 26 [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/05/questions-python-for-data-science/)

Given

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
```

we want to return all values in a which are also in b.  The way I tried to do this is

```
[i for i in a and i in b]
```

However, Python throws an error because it reads b as a bool for some reason, and is therefore unable to iterate over b.

I find this strange because b is not read as a bool when we write

```
[i for i in a if i in b]
```

Furthermore, b is correctly read as a list when we exchange "and" for "or":

```
[i for i in a or i in b]
```

Why is b read as a bool rather than a list when we use "and"?

Comment: Do google search `Syntax of list comprehension`

Comment: `[i for i in a and i in b]` is `[i for i in (a and (i in b))]`... Unless `i` is already defined *outside* the list comprehension, that's a `NameError`. If `i` *is* defined, unless `a` is empty (and therefore false-y) you end up trying to iterate over `i in b`, which is either `true` or `false` (and therefore not iterable).

Comment: You could try solution with sets: `set(a).intersection(b)`

Comment: `[i for i in a or i in b]` works because `a` is non-empty, and therefore truthy, so `(a or (i in b))` evaluates to `a`, which is iterable. If `a` was empty, it would evalulate to `i in b`, either `true` or `false`.

Comment: `[i for i in a or i in b]` is parsed as `[i for i in (a or i in b)]`, so `(a or i in b)` is the expression supplying the iterable for the `for` loop. Since `a` is a non-empty list, and `or` short-circuits, you end up with `i for i in a`. You really want to [revisit the basics of list comprehensions](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2020.html#sec224), because the base syntax always required `if` when filtering.

Comment: (and in the same vein, `[i for i in a and i in b]` is `[i for i in (a and i in b)]` so `(a and i in b)` is the iterable; `and` switches returns the right-hand expression result when `a` is true, which it is, and `i` is not yet defined so you get a name error. Or `i` *is* defined (in the parent scope of the list comprehension, the iterator part is evaluated before the comprehension scope is set up), and so `a and i in b` produces `True` or `False`, neither of which can be iterated over. You effectively created a `[i for i in True]` or `[i for i in False]` list comprehension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of a list comprehension is:

```
[ <expression> for <variable> in <sequence> <optional predicate> ]
```

The optional predicate is introduced with the `if` keyword. Since your list comprehension doesn't contain `if`, it's treating `a and i in b` as an expression that should return a sequence.

This shouldn't treat `b` as a boolean, though. `in` has higher precedence than `and`, so this should be parsed as `(a and (i in b))`. Since `a` is non-empty, it's truthy, so your list comprehension is equivalent to

```
[i for i in (i in b)]
```

This will not work. If there's no `i` variable already in scope, it will get a Name Error.

If there is an `i` variable, `i in b` will evaluate to a boolean. This will get a Type Error because it's not a sequence that can be iterated.